# Why do Indian women wear Bichhia (Toe Rings)?

Tags: tradition, women

There are various traditions followed in India like married Indian women wear toe rings. It is worn as a symbol of the married state by Hindu women. Indian tradition says that married women are expected to wear silver made toe-rings on the second toe of both feet. Hence there is a custom in Hindu wedding ceremony to wear toe rings. What benefits do these bring to them according to Hindu scripture?

Comment: Asking for scientific reason is off-topic. In the second paragraph, you answered your own question upto some extent!!!

Comment: I am asking about the benefits how toe rings . Scientific is secondary.

Comment: @SreeCharan I have seen you editing  my questions  but whatever you edit is similar to the one I have asked. I do not find a vast difference in grammar concerned.

Comment: See these [revisions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/19703/revisions). I didn't correct grammar. I corrected capital letters in the middle of the sentence and tags.